# The Selected Component should not display menu

Tags: reactjs

Goal:
Display the navigation's menu when you select 'Home' but not 'About'

Problem:
Today, if you select navigation link Home or About, you always gonna see the menu.

Is it possible to select 'About' without displaying the navigation's menu?

Info:
*I'm newbie in Reactjs
*The navigation's list can be many links for instance 20 different links or less. For instance, Index, About, Service, Contact Us etc.
*This is a simplifed version when you have only two links that is Home, About. In reality it can be more navigation link in the menu.

Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-k19hye?

Thank you!

---

```
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

const HomePage = () => <h1>Home Page</h1>;
const AboutPage = () => <h1>About Page</h1>;

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        {/* Router component can have only 1 child. We'll use a simple
          div element for this example. */}
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
          <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this would be to use a `Switch` and move the `AboutPage` route before the `Nav`. This way you don't have to add `Nav` to every component if you have a lot of pages

```html
import React from 'react';
import './style.css';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Nav = () => (
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

const HomePage = () => <h1>Home Page</h1>;
const AboutPage = () => <h1>About Page</h1>;

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      name: 'React',
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        {/* Router component can have only 1 child. We'll use a simple
          div element for this example. */}
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/about" component={AboutPage} />
            <div>
              <Nav />
              <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} />
            </div>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: It doesn't work when you apply another conponent page.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by that? Adding another page should be as simple as adding it to the Router and the Nav